# UIKit: View controllers loading nib files automatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

It seems like since recent times, view controllers automatically load a nib file with the exact name if one exists.

I can simply initialize a view controller like

```
[[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]
```

and then when pushing it onto a navigation controller or so, the nib gets loaded without me ever doing anything.

This works in my app except for one view controller and I fail to figure out why. All view controllers that do load their nibs automatically have probably been created in Xcode 4, while the only one where it doesn't work was propably created back in Xcode 3. Is there a hidden switch somewhere? I coulud not find anything in the file settings of the nib, the nib itself and nothing in the source code of the view controllers that could explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS has a case-sensitive filesystem, so make sure the case matches.

Double-check that the nib is enabled for the target you are building.

Check you don't have a `loadView` method.

Check [the default handling for the `nibName` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName).

Comment: It seems I found the issue: The view controller for which the automatic nib loading did not work was a subclass of TTViewController of the Three20 framework. TTViewController overrides the loadView method, which in turn seems to stop the automatic nib loading.
One solution is therefore to override the loadView method yourself like

    - (void) loadView {
      [super loadView];
      NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: nibName owner: self options: nil];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Also check to see if the custom class you are calling `init` on does not implement `init` to do something other than calling itself with a `nil` *nibName*.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing is, you should not override the UIViewController if you want to load the nib file automatically.